# Detect systemd service restart using prometheus

Tags: systemd, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

I want to trigger an alert if a systemd service restarts. If I am able to capture time between a service inactive and active state, then I think I am able to create such alert. We know we can delay triggering an alert by using:

```
- alert: TestAlert
  expr: service_inactive == 1
  for: 1m
```

Instead of triggering above alert I want to store it's output to track the time and use an expression like: if the time between inactive to active state is < 1m then it means that the service has been restarted. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to track changes in the actual "start time" timestamp? I'm unfamiliar with prometheus, but systemd always keeps track of the date/time when the service was started (including restarts) – a change would indicate the service has been restarted.